# AngularStrap Checkbox button ng-repeat Object selection not reflected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-strap

I am using AngularStrap checkbox button where checkbox items come from server.  So, I am trying to use `ng-repeat`, but I am not able to see the values of the item selected.  Please see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/597NRyYpYRiItkYcz1hk) where I have 3 types of checkboxes in it -

1. A regular checkbox and it works.
2. Bootstrap checkbox using `ng-repeat`.  It does not reflect selected object values.
3. Bootstrap checkbox where items are repeated.  It works.

Please help me to fix #2 above where I am using `ng-repeat` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the extra tag around the button element:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jRIedNZdqZ4phdDk21Vw?p=preview

```
  <div class="btn-group" bs-buttons-checkbox>
            <button ng-repeat="item in items" type="button" class="btn" ng-model="selection.ids[item.id]">{{item.name}}</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've fixed the plunkr.  It was referencing a file that was no longer there.